# Ninject + Web ApI 2: Error activating IFilterProvider using binding from IFilterProvider to DefaultFilterProvider

Tags: ninject, ninject-2, ninject-extensions

I originally had used some custom code I found to handle the dependency resolution in Web API and it worked fine. The issue I ran into was that I wanted to bind a filter to my controller scopes just like you can with MVC. For example, Kernel.BindFilter. The new Ninject.We.WebApi package has the binding extension I want but as soon as I add it to my project I get the following error. I'm not changing any of my code, just referencing a DLL.

> Error activating IFilterProvider using binding from IFilterProvider to
>   DefaultFilterProvider  A cyclical dependency was detected between the
>   constructors of two services.
>
> Activation path:  3) Injection of dependency IFilterProvider into
>   parameter defaultFilterProviders of constructor of type
>   DefaultFilterProviders  2) Injection of dependency
>   DefaultFilterProviders into parameter filterProviders of constructor
>   of type DefaultFilterProvider  1) Request for IFilterProvider
>
> Suggestions:  1) Ensure that you have not declared a dependency for
>   IFilterProvider on any implementations of the service.  2) Consider
>   combining the services into a single one to remove the cycle.  3) Use
>   property injection instead of constructor injection, and implement
>   IInitializable  if you need initialization logic to be run after
>   property values have been injected.
>
> at Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()    at
>   Ninject.KernelBase.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__f(IBinding binding)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__b1`1.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.d__14`2.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   Ninject.Web.WebApi.Filter.DefaultFilterProvider.GetFilters(HttpConfiguration
>   configuration, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor.b__0(IFilterProvider
>   fp)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.d__14`2.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.d__0.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.d__a0`1.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor.<RemoveDuplicates>d__3.MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.<ReverseIterator>d__a0`1.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor.InitializeFilterPipeline()
>   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Lazy`1.get_Value()    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor.GetFilterPipeline()
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor.GetFilterGrouping()
>   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__0.MoveNext()

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else is looking for a potential solution for cyclical dependency for the IFilterProvider, I had to explicitly bind DefaultFilterProviders like this

```
k.Bind<DefaultFilterProviders>().ToConstant(new DefaultFilterProviders(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetFilterProviders()));
```

or this

```
k.Bind<DefaultFilterProviders>().ToSelf().WithConstructorArgument(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetFilterProviders());
```

If anyone else knows a better way I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I added the Nuget package Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebHost.

Comment: Could you please explain how you solved the problem?

Comment: Sure, I added the "Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebHost" package to my project. This package is not pulled in automatically so you need to manually add it.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it didn't help me

Comment: Me neither. I still having the same problem.